# Cfloop only returning values for the first and last values of a list

Tags: coldfusion, cfloop

Long story short, I'm working on an application where CRUD is performed against a MySQL database. Everything is working great, except on the updating portion. I have an HTML form that the user submits to the database, and a separate page where a specific record (event) is pulled back into the form and populates the inputs. All of the other inputs are working properly, but my checkbox block is struggling.

Each checkbox input tag has this associated ColdFusion code (cfloop, cfif). The loop determines if the value is included in the list returned from the database and displays "Checked" if true:

```
<!--Each input has a cfloop and cfif tag to determine checked checkboxes-->
<input
  type="checkbox"
  id="alumni_relations"
  value="Alumni Relations"
  name="cboxes"
  <cfloop index="foundRecord.event_type" list="#foundRecord.event_type#" delimiters=",">
    <cfoutput>
      <cfif #foundRecord.event_type# EQ "Alumni Relations">Checked</cfif>
    </cfoutput>
  </cfloop>
>
<label for="alumni_relations">Alumni Relations</label>
<br>
```

It works great! But for whatever reason it is only returning "Checked" for the first listed, and last listed item in the list (e.g a list of: Alumni Relations,Athletics,Management Society,Colleges will only return "Checked" for Alumni Relations and Athletics) Here's a picture of that:

Checkbox Example Image

[image: Checkbox Example Image]

I'm thinking it has to do something with the index, but I've scoured the documentation for cfloop and I'm just not figuring it out. Anyone with any help/advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: just a, suggestion, but, it'd probably be simpler to just search the list with listfind or listcontains, than to loop over it. But understanding why the loop isn't working might be educational.

Comment: @KevinB That's a good idea, my only hold up is that there are 9 possible checkboxes and 1-9 could be checked. So if I did a listFind or listContains I would have to have an OR statement for 1-9 since the returned index could in theory be at any position in the list. Does that make sense?

Comment: if the return is not 0, then you know it is in the list, and therefore should be checked, right?

Comment: Just replace the `<cfloop>....</cfloop>` with `<cfif foundRecord.event_type.listFind("Alumni Relations")>Checked</cfif>`

Comment: The issue with your code could be one of scoping.  That is, your `index` and `list` attributes for your `<cfloop>` both use the same variable.  If you want to keep the code as is, you can change it to `index="i"` and `<cfif i EQ "Alumni Relations">Checked</cfif>`.

Comment: Man, I'm thankful that there are smart people like you guys here. I'm quite new to all of this so I appreciate the insights! @KevinB

Comment: @MasonPerry - Agreed on using list functions instead, but use ListFind/FindNoCase - not ListContains. The latter is for finding substrings, not whole values. Also 1) No need for the cfoutput in the orginal code, as you are not outputting any CF variables 2) Consider using a numeric record ID for the input values, instead of text, as any commas in the event names will break your code